# How to implement auto suggestion feature in microsoft bot framework in node js?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to have auto suggestion in my bot framework.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Please show us your progress so far.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I have not started development so far. I wanted to know if there are any plugins available. I dint find.

Answer (score 0):

I think [adding suggested actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to messages for answers would be good to start with.

Here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#suggested-actions-example):

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .text("Thank you for expressing interest in our premium golf shirt! What color of shirt would you like?")
    .suggestedActions(
        builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                session, [
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=green", "Green"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=blue", "Blue"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=red", "Red")
                ]
            ));
session.send(msg);
```